# How to merge specific lines positioned between certain characters

Tags: python, text, merge, lines

I want to use python or shell script to edit the following file so that blocks of lines that do not start with the character > are merged together into one line.

```
>Entry1
ABCDEFGHIJ
KLMNOPQRST
>Entry2
PQRSTUVWXY
ZABCJRISKJ
JJSKWIOFJA
>Entry3
UWHJSHKAHJ
```

should become:

```
>Entry1
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST
>Entry2
PQRSTUVWXYZABCJRISKJJJSKWIOFJA
>Entry3
UWHJSHKAHJ
```

The number of lines is not the same for each entry (their length is however constant) and some entries only have a single line. What would be the easiest way to proceed?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**file.txt**

```
PQRSTUVWXY
ZABCJRISKJ
JJSKWIOFJA
```

**script.py**

```
with open('file.txt') as file:
    print(file.read().replace('\n', ''))
```

will output `PQRSTUVWXYZABCJRISKJJJSKWIOFJA`